# Three js shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer, shadows, light

I've been working on scene in tree.js to help understand how to create a scene similarly to how I would in 3dsMax. I'm at the point where I'm trying to add shadows.

From what I've read I should be seeing a shadow on the ground, cast by lightSpot_Right, and barStool being the occlusion object. But I'm not! If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated!

```
///webGL - Locking down the Basics
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Environment Settings///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Renderer 
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

///Camera's
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
scene.add(camera);

var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(1, 1000, 256); // parameters: near, far, resolution
cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter; // mipmap filter
scene.add(cubeCamera);

camera.position.set(0, 16, 25);
camera.rotation.x += -0.32;

///Controls



///Lights

var lightSpot_Right = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
lightSpot_Right.position.set(50, 50, 0);
lightSpot_Right.castShadow = true;
lightSpot_Right.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
lightSpot_Right.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
lightSpot_Right.shadowCameraNear = 500;
lightSpot_Right.shadowCameraFar = 4000;
lightSpot_Right.shadowCameraFov = 30;
scene.add(lightSpot_Right);

var lightDirect_Left = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.25);
lightDirect_Left.position.set(-1, 0, 0);
scene.add(lightDirect_Left);

//var lightAmb = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x262626); // soft white light
//scene.add(lightAmb);

///Loaders
var loadTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

///skyBox
var imagePrefix = "textures/";
var directions = ["skyboxRight", "skyboxLeft", "skyboxTop", "skyboxBottom", "skyboxFront", "skyboxBack"];
var imageSuffix = ".jpg";

var skyMaterialArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    skyMaterialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(imagePrefix + directions[i] + imageSuffix),
        side: THREE.BackSide
    }));
var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(skyMaterialArray);


var skyGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(500, 500, 500);
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeometry, skyMaterial);
scene.add(skyBox);

var groundPlaneMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({


})

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Object Settings//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Textures
var seatTexture = loadTexture.load("textures/Maharam_Mister_Notice_Diffuse.jpg");

var conceteDiffuse = loadTexture.load("textures/Contrete_Diffuse.jpg");
var conceteNormal = loadTexture.load("textures/Contrete_Normal.jpg");
var conceteSpecular = loadTexture.load("textures/Contrete_Specular.jpg");

///Materials
var seatMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: seatTexture,
    side: THREE.doubleside
});
var frameMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget,
    color: 0xcccccc

});
var frameHardwareMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
});
var feetMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x050505,
    shininess: 99
});

var sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget

});

var groundMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: conceteDiffuse,
    specularMap: conceteSpecular
});

///Geometry and Meshes
var barStool = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(barStool);
barStool.castShadow = true;

var seatMesh;
loader.load("models/stoolSeat.js", function (geometry, material) {
    seatMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, seatMaterial);
    seatMesh.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(seatMesh);

});

var frameMesh;
loader.load("models/stoolFrame.js", function (geometry, material) {
    frameMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, frameMaterial);
    frameMesh.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(frameMesh);

});

var frameFeetMesh;
loader.load("models/stoolFeet.js", function (geometry, material) {
    frameFeetMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, feetMat);
    frameFeetMesh.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(frameFeetMesh);
});

var frameHardwareMesh;
loader.load("models/stoolHardware.js", function (geomtry, material) {
    frameHardwareMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geomtry, frameHardwareMat);
    frameHardwareMesh.scale.set(.5, .5, .5);
    barStool.add(frameHardwareMesh);
});


var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2.5, 50, 50);
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
scene.add(sphereMesh);

sphereMesh.position.set(-10, 5, 0);

var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 50, 1);
var groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo, groundMat);
scene.add(groundMesh);

groundMesh.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI / 180;
groundMesh.receiveShadow = true;


///Render Scene

var render = function () {

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    barStool.rotation.y += 0.01;

    sphereMesh.visible = false;
    cubeCamera.position.copy(sphereMesh.position);
    cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
    sphereMesh.visible = true;
    /*
    frameMesh.visible = false;
    cubeCamera.position.copy(frameMesh.position);
    cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(renderer, scene);
    frameMesh.visible = true;
    */
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

Comment: So I finally got my shadows working correctly.  However i have been unable to control the darkness of the shadows.  From what I've found online you're suppose to add light.shadowDarkness to the corresponding light.  However I've also read that that attribute is no longer available in the new versions of three.js.  Does anyone know how to control the shadow darkness/intensity?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  I should of been assigning .castShadow = true; to the mesh objects instead of setting it to barStool which is an empty Object3D whom is the parent of the meshes that contain the stool.